# merging running total query in a single result MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have this query result for each type and it looks like this.

```
Type | Date_Registered | subTotal | TotalSum
-----+-----------------+-----------+---------
  A  | 2005-05-24      | 8        |    8
  A  | 2005-05-25      | 37       |    45
  A  | 2005-05-26      | 74       |    119
  A  | 2005-05-27      | 66       |    185
  A  | 2005-05-28      | 96       |    281
---------------------------------------------
Type | Date_Registered | subTotal | TotalSum
-----+-----------------+-----------+---------
  B  | 2005-05-20      | 41        |    41
  B  | 2005-05-21      | 31        |    72
  B  | 2005-05-24      | 14        |    86
  B  | 2005-05-26      | 51        |    137
  B  | 2005-05-27      | 81        |    218
```

this is my query for each type i made this result separately

```
SELECT t.type, t.Date_Registered,
                    t.subTotal,
                    @running_total:=@running_total + t.total AS TotalSum
            FROM
            ( SELECT
            type,
            SUBSTR(dateCreated,1,10) as Date_Registered,
            COUNT(*) as subTotal
            FROM tableA
            WHERE type = 'A'
            GROUP BY SUBSTR(dateCreated,1,10) ) t
            JOIN (SELECT @running_total:=0) r
            ORDER BY t.Date_Registered
```

I wanted to merge this 2 total column result in a single query that would look like this

```
Date_Registered  |    A   |   B
-----------------+--------+--------
2005-05-20       |  0     |   41
2005-05-21       |  0     |   72
2005-05-24       |  8     |   86
2005-05-25       |  45    |   86
2005-05-26       |  119   |   137
2005-05-27       |  185   |   218
2005-05-28       |  281   |   218
```

each total count for each day will be added to the next day and since B doesn't have count for date 05-25 the prev total will be displayed instead.

**EDIT:**

my sample record looks like this

```
    Type |    Date_Registered       | username  
    -----+--------------------------+-----------
      A  |    2005-05-24 12:12:31   | user1         
      A  |    2005-05-24 12:12:31   | user2
      B  |    2005-05-25 03:04:45   | user3       
      B  |    2005-05-27 05:04:45   | user4      
      A  |    2005-05-27 07:04:45   | user5
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of rows from your table? This looks doable with a `SUM(CASE...)` instead of `COUNT(*)` aggregate.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i updated my question with the sample record

Answer (score 0):

By using two counters, and `SUM(Type='A')` as a substituent for `COUNT`. `Type='A'` is a boolean `0` or `1` value.

Using string functions on dates is evil. Assuming `dateCreated` is `timestamp` or `datetime` the `DATE()` function is used. If its just a `DATE` type, there's no need for a function.

```
SELECT t.Date_Registered,
                @running_total_a:=@running_total_a + t.ATotal AS A,
                @running_total_b:=@running_total_b + t.BTotal AS B

        FROM
        ( SELECT
        DATE(dateCreated) as Date_Registered,
        SUM(type='A') as ATotal,
        SUM(type='B') as BTotal
        FROM tableA
        WHERE type IN ('A','B')
        GROUP BY Date_Registered ) t
        JOIN (SELECT @running_total_a:=0,@running_total_b:=0 ) r
        ORDER BY t.Date_Registered
```

Comment: im using datatype datetime for dateCreated and when i tried it using sum data returns null

Comment: fixed lines 2,3 that where using the old user variable name.